# How can I show only the years with a DateEdit in C# with DevExpress?

Tags: c#, calendar, devexpress

I want to show a calendar with years only, not days nor months. 
Preferably with the `DateEdit` that **DevExpress** provides.

Comment: Thanks for editing Muhammad Omar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task by handling the DateEdit.Popup event:

```
private void dateEdit1_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateEdit edit = sender as DateEdit;
        PopupDateEditForm form = (edit as IPopupControl).PopupWindow as PopupDateEditForm;
        form.Calendar.View = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.DateEditCalendarViewType.YearInfo;
    }
```

more info [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q216523)

Comment: I want to add that this solution is just for the users of DevExpress 15.2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PopupDateEditForm` will only format the view. But the user has to select the date at last.

Only showing and selecting Year can be achieve using this -

```
RepositoryItemDateEdit dropDownYear = new RepositoryItemDateEdit();
dropDownYear.Mask.EditMask = "yyyy";
dropDownYear.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
dropDownYear.VistaCalendarViewStyle = VistaCalendarViewStyle.YearsGroupView;

this.ColumnYear.ColumnEdit = dropDownYear;
```

Here I bind `DateEdit` repo to GridCOlumn.

[image]